# JAVA Applet Loading Issue

Tags: java, security, jnlp, japplet, digital-certificate

We have developed an applet in JAVA which is mainly used for accessing Digital Certificate from keystore.

The applet works fine in most of the cases, but in some secure networks of banks the applet behaviour becomes unpredictable.

We are using applet tag in HTML to access applet.

My first question is do we need to deploy using JNLP for this?

Secondly, I prepared one test application in past where by I was simply calling one method of applet, which was loading all the certificate public details and printing it on console. It used to work perfectly ok.

Following is the code for the same.

Applet Method

```
   public void init() {
    printMessageToConsole("Applet Initialized Version : " + appletVersion);
    browserName = "Internet Explorer";
    try {
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        printMessageToConsole("Operating system name =>" + osName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        printMessageToConsole("Error in Get OS Init.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 public List<String> getCertificateAllDetails() throws NoSuchFieldException,
        SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException,
        InvocationTargetException {
    printMessageToConsole("Get All Certificate Details");
    String certString = "";
    int count =0;
    String pubKey = "";
    KeyStore browserKeyStore = null;
    String certDetails = "";
    browserKeyStore = initializeBrowserKeyStore();
    List<String> resultValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    String aliasnew = null;

    printMessageToConsole(browserName);
    if (browserKeyStore != null) {
        printMessageToConsole("INSIDE IE CERTIFICATE READING");
        Field spiField = KeyStore.class.getDeclaredField("keyStoreSpi");
        spiField.setAccessible(true);
        KeyStoreSpi spi = (KeyStoreSpi) spiField.get(browserKeyStore);
        Field entriesField = spi.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("entries");
        entriesField.setAccessible(true);
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Collection entries = (Collection) entriesField.get(spi);
        resultValues.add("Total Certificates in Browser : " + entries.size() + "<br><br><br>");
        printMessageToConsole("Total Certificates in Browser : " + entries.size());
        for (Object entry : entries) {
            aliasnew = (String) invokeGetter(entry, "getAlias");
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) invokeGetter(entry,"getPrivateKey");
            X509Certificate[] certificateChain = (X509Certificate[]) invokeGetter(entry, "getCertificateChain");
            for (X509Certificate current : certificateChain) {
                certString = "";
                if (certDetails != null && getkeyUsage(current.getKeyUsage()) != "") {
                    count ++;
                    pubKey = this.bASE64Encoder.encode(current.getPublicKey().getEncoded());
                    certDetails = getX509CertificateDetails(current);
                    Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    valueMap = getMetadata(certDetails);
                    certString += "====================== Certificate Details for Certificate No : " + count + "======================<br>";
                    certString += "Alias : " + aliasnew + " <br>";
                    certString += "Name : "+ valueMap.get(CERT_DETAILS.NAME) + " <br>";
                    certString += "Key Usage : " + getkeyUsage(current.getKeyUsage()) + "<br>";
                    certString += "CNName : "+ valueMap.get(CERT_DETAILS.CN_NAME) + "<br>";
                    printMessageToConsole(certString);
                    resultValues.add(certString);
                    break;
                } else {
                    printMessageToConsole("Cert Details is NULL");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printMessageToConsole("Keystore is NULL");
    }

    return resultValues;
}
```

HTML Page

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function getAllCertificates()
    {
        document.write("Certificate Reading Started.")
        var certificates = document.securityApplet.getCertificateAllDetails();
        document.write(certificates);


    }
</SCRIPT>
<body>
    <div>Digital Certificate Test Application</div>
    <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

    <applet name="securityApplet" code="SecurityApplet.class"
    archive="securityApplet.jar" width="0" height="0" MAYSCRIPT="true"
    scriptable="true" > </applet>
    <button type="button" onclick="getAllCertificates()">Load Certificates!</button>

</body>
```

I recently opened up this page and now in my local network the applet is getting initialised properly but then it is unable to call anything further on click of button.

Console Output on loading of page.

```
Applet Initialized Version : 30
Operating system name =>Windows 7
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

Everything is ok till above on loading

When I click on Load Certificate Button, following is the console log and then nothing happens. And in the secured network the last two line even does not come.

```
basic: Starting applet teardown
basic: Finished applet teardown
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1b9bbe8
plugin2manager.parentwindowDispose
```

Following is the console output, where it goes in loop.

Looking forward for an answer on the same. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the problem.
There is nothing to do JNLP here.
The only problem is I have done document.write which is blocking and getting applet to dispose.
I have removed the document.write from HTML and with following HTML the code works completely ok.

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title> Digital Certificate Test Application </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
 <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <applet name="securityApplet" code="SecurityApplet.class"
    archive="securityApplet.jar" width="0" height="0" MAYSCRIPT="true"
    scriptable="true" > </applet> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

    function getAllCertificates()
    {
        alert("Certificate Reading Started");
        var certificates = document.securityApplet.getCertificateAllDetails();
        document.getElementById("displaymessage").innerHTML = certificates;
    }
</SCRIPT>
<body>
    <div>Digital Certificate Test Application</div>
    <div id="displaymessage">

    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="getAllCertificates()">Load Certificates!</button>

</body>
```